# Batch to filter out duplicates in separate directories

Tags: batch-file, find, delete-file

I have two folders two different locations with a bunch of automatically generated (generated through install and repair/ reset) files in them.

Occasionally what happens is that a file of a particular name and extension is found in both folders which causes errors in the associated program, the solution is to delete one of the two so only one remains.

I use batch at work mostly the novice xcopy and so on commands, how if can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: what did you try to solve this yourself, and where is your problem?

Comment: dint see your comment there till just i hav come up with the following but if fails to work..

Comment: for %%f in (C:\1\*) do set FILENAME1=%%~nxf

if exist "C:\2\%FILENAME1%" del "C:\1\%FILENAME1%"

Comment: nevermind this fixed it: for /r C:\1\ %%f in (*) do if exist "C:\2\%%~nxf" del /s /q "C:\1\%%~nxf"

Comment: if you have fixed it, please post it as an answer, and accept that answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> Never mind this fixed it:
>
> ```
> for /r C:\1\ %%f in (*) do if exist "C:\2\%%~nxf" del /s /q "C:\1\%%~nxf
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)).